# Disable evil-mode in magit

Tags: magit, evil

I am newbie here, need some help.

After upgrade magit to v2.1.0 this morning, i found some short keys are different from the early version. What bothers me is this:

when I use some short key(for example 'b'), it shows the option windows, in early version, i just type another short key in the option window to do the action (like checkout branch). But now in v2.1.0 i find i can't do it anymore. As I use evil-mode for vim operation, the option windows is in evil-mode, and i only can use magit short key after i enter the insert mode of evil-mode.

Can anyone tells me how to disable evil-mode in the whole magit?

Comment: What I would recommend is to only enable `evil-local-mode` for the modes you actually need Evil in (e.g. writing text modes, programming modes). You can do this with hooks. And optionally you can have a handy key-binding to toggle `evil-local-mode` on demand. (e.g. http://www.john2x.com/emacs.html#sec-8-19). Alternatively, you can toggle Evil's "emacs mode" by pressing `C-z`.

Comment: Don't. [Evil is intended to be used as global mode](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/544/disparity-between-local-and-global-mode).

Comment: I did not know that. Yeah, that `show-paren` thing has been bugging me for a long time. I didn't realize it was because I was using `evil-local-mode`. I guess it's time to shave some yaks.

Answer (score 7):

Evil has the concept of *states* (just like modes in Vim).  Customize the initial state of Magit buffers to not be `normal` anymore:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-core
  '(evil-set-initial-state 'magit-popup-mode 'emacs))
```

Alternatively, upgrade your Evil installation because this got added to their whitelist of initial states :)

Comment: Would it be possible to do the reverse? Make emacs as the default state, and only set to normal state on select modes?

Comment: Sure, but it would be even more tedious to do so unless you have a hack to make the lookup of the initial state somewhat automatic.  An example of this can be found in my [init.org](https://github.com/wasamasa/dotemacs/blob/master/init.org#initial-state).

Comment: [I've got in contact with upstream](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/497/regarding-initial-states), but there hasn't been much of a reaction yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
            '(lambda () 
               (evil-mode (if (or (equal major-mode 'magit-log-mode) (equal major-mode 'magit-popup-mode) (equal major-mode 'magit-status-mode)(equal major-mode 'magit-mode)) 0 1))))
```

But magit is a set of major mode and it will not work every where. For example the commit window is in text-mode so you need to add text-mode

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
                '(lambda () 
                   (evil-mode (if (or (equal major-mode 'text-mode) (equal major-mode 'magit-log-mode) (equal major-mode 'magit-popup-mode) (equal major-mode 'magit-status-mode)(equal major-mode 'magit-mode)) 0 1))))
```

But now text-mode is not in evil-mode so...
Maybe the good solution is https://github.com/tarleb/evil-rebellion

Regards